# Blank monitor after installing GPU

Tags: desktop, gpu, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron

I recently bought a factory refurbished Dell Inspiron 3000 Desktop. It's equipped with a Core i5 4460 CPU with 8gb RAM. The motherboard is a Dell model 088DT1. I'm running Windows 8.1 64bit. (link to my model here: http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-3847-desktop/pd?oc=fdcwrp201s&model_id=inspiron-3847-desktop)

My previous desktop had a slim case, so I had purchased a Sapphire Radeon HD 7750 Low Profile graphics card for it (link here: http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?pid=1658&lid=1).

The card works. I know that for sure because it was working 3 days ago in my old PC before I set up my new Dell.

The computer works fine. But I don't want to use the integrated graphics, I want to use my 7750. So I put the 7750 in the regular sized bracket so that it will fit in the new PC, plugged it into the PCI-E slot, connected it to a DVI cable which is connected to my monitor, and turned on the computer. But the screen stays blank. Nothing shows up, even though the computer is running. No start up screen or anything. The monitor stays in power-saving mode.

The GPU is running fine, because the cooling fans are spinning. So I'm not sure what the problem is. I also don't think it's my power supply (300watt), because I tested it with a PSU from a separate computer which is 500watts and it still didn't work. I know the specs for the graphics card says a minimum of 400watt power supply, but it ran fine on my older computer, and I've used 4 different power supply calculators on the internet and they all recommend ~270 watts for my current setup...

If I disconnect the DVI connector and reconnect the VGA, when I boot the computer up I get a screen that basically tells me a GPU was detected and I need to use the DVI cable... so apparently the BIOS is recognizing the newly installed GPU.

Speaking of, I updated the BIOS and updated the Chipset. Didn't fix it. I went into the BIOS settings because I read that sometimes you need to explicitly have the BIOS use the graphics card in the PCI-E slot instead of onboard.... but there's no option for that in the BIOS menu. So I'm assuming it looks for it automatically, anyway.

I'm stumped and don't know what to do. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just insert the graphic card into the slot and that's it?  Because once you insert it, generally you should make sure the cable that goes from power supply into the graphic card is also properly inserted.

Comment: Yes. But I thought it was getting power from the power supply, because the cooling fans on the GPU are running.

Comment: The fans would spin even if you didn't have the cable plugged into your gpu. The only difference would be that if it's not connected then the fans would usually spin much faster than when I have it plugged in. When u plug it in and start the computer, it would spin up then reduce its speed to a point where u barely even hear it. How many PCI-E slots have u got in it? Can you try inserting the gpu into another slot and test it?

Comment: I only have one PCI-E slot. I'm not very good with computers when it comes to hardware, how can I check/be sure that the GPU is connected to the power supply? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking at my card (Radeon HD 7750) it doesn't have a power connection so I think you just plug it into the slot. I just plugged it into the slot on my old PC and it worked fine.

Comment: Try this..  remove new card. Reconnect vga. Start Windows in safe mode. Go to control panel and find device manager. Under display adapter find intel graphics driver. Right click it, disable it. Press start and type msconfig and press enter. Unclick safe boot. Shut down your pc, insert the new card,  and restart the machine

Comment: Okay I will try that. But what happens if I still get a blank screen? The Intel graphics driver will be disabled, so I'll have no way of interacting with the OS... or no? Again, I appreciate your help. I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Comment: To be safe, restart he machine with vga when Intel is disabled. If it works then try the new card

Comment: Tried everything you said, didn't work. :(

Comment: Have you got another card to test? Sound to me even though it's a refurbished unit, there is a possibility that the PCI-E slot may be faulty.

Comment: I have a feeling you may be right :( and I might have one to test, I'll write back if I do.

Comment: So I found an old nVIDIA GeFore 8500GT, the only problem is that it is a low profile card and the low profile bracket is like welded to the card. So even if I found a full sized bracket I couldn't replace it...

Comment: Ok nevermind I was able to remove the bracket and just hook it up to the slot. Still black screen. So does that pretty much confirm that the PCI-E slot is faulty?

Comment: Did you purchase this dell unit from Dell or from a dell reseller? If so, there is a possibility that the system could still be under warranty. If this is the case, I would highly contacting Dell, and provide them a service tag found on your PC(either on top of tower or back of tower), if it's under warranty, they would possibly be able to get a tech out and either replace the unit or get it tested in the lab. I used to be a Dell Field Technician here in Western Australia, so I used to do a lot of dell warranty repairs. Give it a go.

Comment: Yup the computer came with a 1yr warranty. I will surely be contacting them. Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: If it still goes blank, then big chance it could be faulty. Though can you post a picture of BIOS, I think there was a setting in there if I can recall that dealt with onboard or PCI-E. I know you said you couldn't find it, but I would like to make sure of that. Otherwise yeah if you got warranty, get dell to get someone out to replace it. They are awesome for things like this

Comment: What tab would the option be in? "Advanced"? I will look again and take a picture.

Comment: This is the main screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xq4siua2n8kmukg/IMG_0420.JPG?dl=0, this is the advanced tab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipwaroow0yv35kz/image1.JPG?dl=0, this is the "Onboard device configuration" menu in the advanced tab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nyk5cy8g1bkgmhx/image2.JPG?dl=0, and this is the boot tab: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ddp1e06r0i85mp/image3.JPG?dl=0

Comment: OMG, I feel so dumb. I talked with a Dell tech representative. The issue was that I needed to change the input on my monitor. Ugh! Weird because I've never had to do that manually before. My GPU works now!

Comment: Haha. I knew we were missing something. I'm glad it works and it came through. And mostly glad it wasn't your motherboard :)